# Can I generate JPA metamodels and QueryDSL models in same project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a project where we have code implemented using JPA and we use metamodels. To generate hibernate metamodels we use following as a maven plaugin

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations/</outputDirectory>
              <processors>
                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
              </processors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Now we like to try out QueryDSL, and I added the maven configuration to generate QueryDSL-models. It looks like following.

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
              <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

But now when I run `maven clean test` it complains that JPA Hibernate metamodels are missing. But if I switch the order then it complaints that other metamodels are missing. So is there a way to use both of them in same porject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data Jpa Query DSL Q Entityclasses not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447728/spring-data-jpa-query-dsl-q-entityclasses-not-generating)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is not the generation itself, but that you have classes in your codebase that depend on the generated classes.
Have you tried to add the generation output directories as source directories like this?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Should work for mvn on CLI as well for m2e in Eclipse.